# python mysql change date to variable?

Tags: python, mysql

when I add clear date into Mysql request its works:

```
mycursor.execute("""
    SELECT msisdn,prefix FROM sms WHERE datum_primanja LIKE '2021-09-01%'  
""")
```

but when how to add date from variable, I tried:

```
dt = date.today() - timedelta(5)

mycursor.execute("SELECT msisdn,prefix FROM sms WHERE datum_primanja LIKE dt%  ")
```

but not works, the goal is to set up a current date -5, this code for date works separately but on the above request not?

how to add date variable into MySQL request ?

Comment: you should format the date to string, what is your question?

Comment: See the following answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173197/5389997

Comment: @BrownBear when you said " format the date to string", how to add it, for example   ...... LIKE   str(dt) %    ?